# Is it necessary to have a reference plane when doing structured-light scanning for depth calculation?

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to create a point cloud of an object using the structured-light approach with either fringe-projection or dot markers but the object I plan on "scanning" won't be in front of a flat background as I've seen with most techniques. I'm assuming it's required to have the reference during calibration but I'm wondering if it's always necessary during the application.

I assume it is not always necessary considering dot projection for facial recognition doesn't need a background behind you but perhaps that's due to the nature of the algorithm. I'm fine with having a relative distance of each point with respect to each other if that is the only way to do it without the reference plane.